# Inheritance in Java and using generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have two implementations of an interface

```
 EncryptionService
  **ABCEncryptionServiceImpl**
     encrypt(byte[] bytes)
     decrypt(byte[] bytes)
  **XYZEncryptionServiceImpl**
     encrypt(List<String> strings)
     decrypt(List<String> strings)
```

What I don't like is I have to:

Provide empty implementation in `ABCEncryptionServiceImpl` for methods:

```
encrypt(List<String> strings)
decrypt(List<String> strings)
```

Provide empty implementation in `XYZEncryptionServiceImpl` for methods:

```
encrypt(byte[] bytes)
decrypt(byte[] bytes)
```

Any ideas on how this issue should be handled in a better way i.e using Generics?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do they have to be empty? Do you want some default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having different methods that take specific types such as `byte[]` and `List<String>`, you can declare a generic type parameter in `EncryptionService`.

```
public interface EncryptionService<T>
{
    public void encrypt(T obj);
    public void decrypt(T obj);
}
```

The implementation classes will define the type parameter to be a concrete type.  This way, neither implementation class will need to provide implementations for encrypting/decrypting a type it doesn't cover.

```
public class ABCEncryptionServiceImpl implements EncryptionService<byte[]>
{
    @Override
    public void encrypt(byte[] obj) { /* implementation */ }
    @Override
    public void decrypt(byte[] obj) { /* implementation */ }
}

public class XYZEncryptionServiceImpl implements EncryptionService<List<String>>
{
    @Override
    public void encrypt(List<String> obj) { /* implementation */ }
    @Override
    public void decrypt(List<String> obj) { /* implementation */ }
}
```

Comment: Does `T` always have to be a mutable class, since you are returning no result ?

Comment: @Dici It depends on the OP's actual return type, which hasn't been specified.

Comment: yep, which is why it is safer to makethe return type generic !

Answer (score 1):

You could add a generic type argument to `EncryptionService`:

```
abstract class EncryptionService<T> {
    public abstract void encrypt(T item);
    public abstract void decrypt(T item);
}
```

You could then specify what data is to be encrypted/decrypted by using it as a type parameter when extending `EncryptionService`:

```
class ABCEncryptionServiceImpl extends EncryptionService<byte[]> {
    public void encrypt(byte[] bytes) {

    }

    public void decrypt(byte[] bytes) {

    }
}

class XYZEncryptionServiceImpl extends EncryptionService<List<String>> {
    public void encrypt(List<String> items) {

    }

   public void decrypt(List<String> items) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as that ? If I missed something in your question, just tell me.

```
public interface EncryptionService<INPUT, OUTPUT> {
     OUTPUT encrypt(INPUT input);
     INTPUT decrypt(OUTPUT output);
}

public class ABCEncryptionServiceImpl extends EncryptionService<List<String>, List<String>> {
     ...
}

public class XYZEncryptionServiceImpl extends EncryptionService<byte[], byte[]> {
     ...
}
```

Comment: what if input is a List and output is a Map for ABCEncryptionServiceImpl

Comment: @Julie Then just change the second type to `Map` : `ABCEncryptionServiceImpl extends EncryptionService<List<String>, Map<String, String>>` my answer is actually the only one hanle to handle this case. All the other answers have chosen a void return type, which won't work for every generic type

Comment: @Julie Pleased to help you ! You can accept the answer if it is helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to make the parameters for encrypt and decrypt generics.

The naive solution would be

```
public interface EncryptionService<T> {
    void encrypt(T data);
    void decrypt(T data);
};
```

Then your implementations would be like

```
public class ABCEncryptionService implements EncryptionService<byte[]> {
    void encrypt(byte[] data){} 
    void decrypt(byte[] data){}
}
```

And

```
public class XYZEncryptionService implements EncryptionService<List<String>> {
    void encrypt(List<String> data){}
    void decrypt(List<String> data){}
}
```

Comment: `byte[]` is not a primitive type, it is an `Array` object .You can use it with generics

Comment: @dici that's worth a -1? Tough crowd.

Comment: Well, maybe I downvote a bit too fast, but I remove it as the answer gets fixed. It also happens to me when I provide a wrong answer !

Comment: I work with like 12 different languages. Can get confusing sometimes. My primary is the .net stack. Arrays are handled differently there than java. No problem though. It needed to be corrected for sure, but all it takes is a comment.